# hg "stream ended unexpectedly" error on cloneing

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone a bit repository from bitbucket via hg but I keep getting this error:

```
abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 404093 bytes, expected 8706452)
```

```
mac:~ user$ hg clone https://user2@bitbucket.org/mine/test
http authorization required
realm: Bitbucket.org HTTP
user: user2
password: 
destination directory: test
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 404093 bytes, expected 8706452)
```

I have tried it twice now but both times it's given the same error.
I have more than enough HDD space.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it failing in the same spot every time? (404093 bytes) If so, then it sounds like there's something wrong on the server side, and you might want to ask them for help.

If its bombing in different places every time then I guess it would be the network.

Comment: Pretty sure it's on the same place. I'll give bitbucket an email in that case. Thanks

Comment: And still waiting... Guess helpdesk isn't there strong point. FYI for other people with the same issue, I ended up getting a zip copy of the entire repo including hg files from another member who had the source already.

Comment: I'm not surprised really. Are you a paying customer? If so this is really inexcusable.

Comment: No, pretty sure we are using a free account.

Comment: This is not an answer, very surprised it was accepted. The error relates to SSH and sshd setup.