# Mercurial on Phabricator: "remote: abort: stream ended unexpectedly"

Tags: mercurial, phabricator

I'm having this problem when trying to push to a remote server. It is a Mercurial repository on Phabricator. Here are my output.

```
hg commit -m "udpate README"
hg push
pushing to ssh://company.server
searching for changes
remote: abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 0 bytes, expected 4)
```

I'm using the latest version of Mercurial `3.5.2+20151001` on Mac OS 10.10.

I have this problem from yesterday. During that time, **I could successfully committed two times**, although I did nothing.

Why the output somewhat looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031708/hg-stream-ended-unexpectedly-error-on-cloneing), the problem here is different, because I have deleted the repository and cloned again many times without any problem. (my first attempt to solve the problem)

The system admin and the server is at another city, so he can't take a look at my machine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like there may be a problem with the server and client disagreeing on the new bundle2 format for the wire protocol introduced in 3.5. I'd recommend trying to temporarily downgrade to v3.4.2 (e.g. with `pip install mercurial==3.4.2`) to see if it fixes this. See [this discussion](https://secure.phabricator.com/T9450). If it doesn't work, try and see what `hg push --debug --traceback` does for you.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends: thank you. I downgrade to 3.4.2, and the problem's gone. Could you turn your comment into an answer so that I can close this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like there may be a problem with the server and client disagreeing on the new bundle2 format for the wire protocol introduced in 3.5. I'd recommend trying to temporarily downgrade to 3.4.2 (e.g. with `pip install mercurial==3.4.2`) to see if it fixes this. See [this discussion on Phabricator](https://secure.phabricator.com/T9450). If it doesn't work, `hg push --debug --traceback` can provide more information on what exactly went wrong.